# Constraint programming framework for scheduling problem

Tags: constraint-programming, scheduled-tasks

I'm going to work on a software application for project planning and I’m looking for a constraint programming library that supports interval arithmetic and constraints on real numbers.

The feature I have to implement is the scheduling of project.

Could you advise me a constraint programming framework for such problem?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: In which language? Many Prolog dialects offer constraint programming out of the box, but the Prolog language itself has a steep learning curve if you're used to only imperative programming.

Comment: As a programming language I use either C#\.Net or C++.

Comment: In Java, I would have suggested Drools Planner. There's now an example that uses double (= real numbers) constraints, but it's easy to hook in BigDecimal or any other number type you'd wish.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a nice book called "Constraint-Based Scheduling: Applying Constraint Programming to Scheduling Problems" co-authored by Philippe Baptiste, Claude Le Pape and Wim Nuijten.

IBM has a commercial tool called ILOG CPLEX specially designed for constraint solving as means of addressing scheduling questions http://www-01.ibm.com/software/integration/optimization/cplex-optimization-studio/ Free alternatives would be GeoCode http://www.gecode.org/ and Minion http://minion.sourceforge.net/ Both are C++-based.

You should however be aware that constraints solving over the reals is not always decidable and would depend on the kind of constraints you intend to use in your modeling. As long as your constraints are linear, you are safe ;-)